# __init__.py file selective import

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

In order to simplify my imports, I added the following code to my `__init__.py`:

```
from varro.algo.models.model import *
from varro.algo.models.fpga import *
from varro.algo.models.nn import *
```

so that I can do `from varro.algo.models import ModelNN`

If I want to import a different kind of model that doesn't require Tensorflow (as `ModelNN` does), I don't want to import it, as it takes a long time to load and may not be installed on all systems I'm working on.

However, importing `from varro.algo.models import ModelFPGA` loads Tensorflow, even though I never import `ModelNN`.

Is there a way I can simplify the imports without having to import `ModelNN` every time? (I figured I could just put the import statement for Tensorflow in the class itself, but I want a more robust solution.)

Comment: Please make your prose and code match. It's unclear which import does what

Comment: Python has the built-in function [`__import__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) which you might be able to use to selectively import submodules in some kind of loop to do what you want.

Comment: There  might be tricks to do what you want. 
Normally if you import something in __init__.py it means you decided to always import it.

Comment: Thank you for posting this question. I am also looking for a solution. Please let know if you were able to solve this issue.

Comment: I ended up simply putting the imports inside an if statement